# Problemas na exibição do relatorio com JasperReport

Tags: java, java-ee, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

No meu trabalho, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação Java EE, com web service REST (Jersey), Hibernate e JQuery no front-end.
Todas as minhas requisições do sistema usam o ajax e estou com dificuldade em gerar o relatório e exibi-lo na tela para o usuário (seja abrindo no browser ou download).

Gostaria de saber a melhor maneira de fazer isso, já vi alguns locais dizendo que não é possivel abrir o PDF recebido pelo Ajax.

Eu possuo alguns filtros que o usuário pode escolher para gerar o relatório e passo esses filtros através de um POST para o web service que me retorna assim (creio que está certo essa parte):

```
File relatorio = gerarRelatorioExtratoVendas(movimentos, usuarioLogado, filtros); 
ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(relatorio); response.type("application/pdf"); 
response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + relatorio.getName()); 
return response.build();
```

Agora preciso recebê-lo e mostrar para o usuário, estou salvando em uma pasta temporária do sistema.

Comment: Pelo que entendi está faltando anexar os bytes do arquivo ao objeto `response`, seria isso? Seria um `response.contentLocation(new URI(relatorio.getPath()));` ? É só um chute, o jeito certo de fazer pode ser algo bem diferente disso!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você deve fazer é testar para ver se a sua API Rest está retornando os dados corretamente. Para retornar um arquivo via rest usando Jax-RS você pode fazer desta maneira:

```
@GET
@Path("/relatorio")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response getFile() {
  File file = gerarRelatorioExtratoVendas(movimentos, usuarioLogado, filtros); 
  return Response.ok(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
      .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" ) //optional
      .build();
}
```

Considerando que o arquivo pdf está realmente sendo gerado no local uma chamada para esta url no seu navegador deveria retornar o relatório.

Uma vez que esta url está gerando o esperado e retornando o relatório vai depender da tecnologia de front end que você está usando para definir a forma como exibi-lo.